# how to write multiple select queries in single procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

I have to tables as:
table1:

```
UID | COLLEGE_NAME | COLLEGE_ADDRESS
------------------------------------
```

table2:

```
UID | COMPANY_NAME | COMPANY_ADDRESS
------------------------------------
```

i have 2 queries:

```
select * from table1 where uid='$uid';   
select * from table2 where uid='$uid';
```

i want to write this two queries in one procedure.

Comment: do you want to combine their result?

Comment: ya i have to combine the results also.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the statement to create `STORED PROCEDURE`.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE procedureName(IN _uid VARCHAR(15))
BEGIN
    SELECT UID, COLLEGE_NAME name, COLLEGE_ADDRESS address
    FROM    table1
    WHERE uid = _uid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UID, COMPANY_NAME name, COMPANY_ADDRESS address
    FROM    table2
    WHERE uid = _uid
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

notice that `UNION` has `ALL` keyword on it to add duplicate records on the result list. But if you prefer `UNIQUE`, remove the `ALL` keyword on the `UNION`.

Comment: what if i don't want to union result, i just want to inherit multiple select queries in procedure then?

Comment: @HarjeetJadeja Why did you accept this answer ? With this answer, you lose the information of whether that UID is for a college or company.

Answer (score 2):

structure for multiple select quires in single procedure:

> `CREATE PROCEDURE` sample(l_uid INT) `BEGIN`
>
> `SELECT` * `FROM` college_edu `WHERE` uid= l_uid;
>
> `SELECT` * `FROM` work_experience `WHERE` uid= l_id;
>
> `END`

Answer (score 0):

below code may serve you purpose. Also the additional tbl column will let you know from which table your data is coming and it would help in further manipulation.

```
 SELECT UID, COLLEGE_NAME name, COLLEGE_ADDRESS address , 1 as tbl
    FROM    table1
    WHERE uid = _uid
    UNION ALL
    SELECT UID, COMPANY_NAME name, COMPANY_ADDRESS address , 2 as tbl
    FROM    table2
    WHERE uid = _uid
```

Comment: what if i don't want to union result, i just want to inherit multiple select queries in procedure then?